# tinyMCE textarea in a tinyMCEPopup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I created a plugin which opens a tinyMCEPopup.
In the tinyMCEPopup I have several textareas and need them to be tinyMCE textareas.
Here is a *simplified* example of the popup file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="multiBoxes">
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="50" rows="15" ></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to init() it or `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'content');` ... but it does not work!
Any suggestion?!

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the correct ids:

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, my_textarea_id);
```

or

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, my_textarea_id);
```

Be aware that those ids need to be unique and that you should remove control onClose of the popup.

Comment: Yes, of course, they are unique, and I check if they are correct... they are =(
Thanks

Comment: my guessi s that you need to call the execCommand from tinyMCEPopup